# Use the most recent date from two date fields (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, expression

I have two datetime fields ("date1" and "date2") and want to use the most resent date to use it in this expression (getting the age in days):

```
round(day(age(now(),"recent_date")),0)
```

"recent_date" should be the the more recent field of "date1" or "date2"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_max`, as it supports `datetime` natively (in contrast to `max` which requires a conversion to `epoch <double>`):

```
round( day( age( now(), array_max( array( "date1", "date2" ) ) ) ), 0 )
```

---

With `epoch` conversion:

```
round( day( age( now(), max( epoch( "date1" ), epoch( "date2" ) ) ) ) ), 0 )
```